# $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]/(3-\sqrt{2})$ is ring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, alternative-proof

> what would be an $n$ such that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]/(3-\sqrt{2})$ is ring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

This problem was on a qualification test. Here's how I solved it, but I'm not satisfied with my answer since it is too intuitive.

Let $I=(3-\sqrt{2})$.
Since $3+I=\sqrt{2}+I$, $9+I=2+I$ hence $7+I=I$. Hence the characteristic of the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]/(3-\sqrt{2})$ is not greater than $7$. For this reason, I expected $n$ would be $7$.

Define $\phi(1)=\bar{1}$ and $\phi(\sqrt{2})=\bar{3}$.

Since $2$ is square-free the function $\phi:\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_7$ is well defined.

Then, it can be directly checked that $\phi$ is a ring epimorphism.

Let $a+b\sqrt{2}\in \ker(\phi)$.

Then, $a+3b \equiv 0 \pmod 7$

Thus for some $k$, $a+3b=7k$.

Note that every element in $(3-\sqrt{2})$ is of the form $3c-2d+\sqrt{2}(3d-c)$.

Define $A=3-2k, B= 3k-1$.

Note that $a+3b=7k=A+3B$.

Thus, $a=A+3l$ and $b=B-l$ for some $l$.

Thus. $a=(3+3l) - 2k , b=3k - (1+l)$. Thus, $a+b\sqrt{2}\in I$.

This shows that $\ker(\phi)=I$. This proves the problem. Q.E.D.

Is there another way to prove this?

Comment: $a+3b=7k;a+b\sqrt{2}=-3b+7k+b\sqrt{2}=-b\left(3-\sqrt{2}\right)+7k\in I$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]/(3-\sqrt{2})\simeq\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-2,3-X)\simeq\mathbb{Z}/(3^2-2)=\mathbb{Z}_7$

The above isomorphism only use the Third isomorphism theorem, that is:

> Given a ring $R$ and two ideals $I\leqslant J$ of $R$, then $(R/I)/(J/I)\simeq R/J$.

Comment: Why does the first isomorphic relation hold?

Comment: @Rubertos The isomorphism identifies $\sqrt{2}$ and $X$. To apply the third isomorphism theorem, check $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2] \cong \mathbb Z[X]/(X^2-2)$ first.

Comment: @Christoph I only know that conjugation for fields.. For what kind of ring $R$, does that conjugation hold? And is there a text introducing this technique? Oh. And I don't get the third isomorphic relation too. Why $(X^2-2,X-3)/(X)\cong \mathh{Z}_7$?

Comment: @Rubertos To see why $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]/(3-\sqrt{2})\simeq\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-2,3-X)$, let $R=\mathbb{Z}[X]$, $J=(X^2-2,3-X)$, $I=(X^2)$; to see why $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-2,3-X)\simeq\mathbb{Z}/(3^2-2)$, let $R=\mathbb{Z}[X]$, $J=(X^2-2,3-X)$, $I=(3-X)$.

Comment: @Rubertos And I think every standard algebra textbook will introduce three isomorphism theorem (of groups and rings, etc.)

Comment: @Rubertos You can also refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem

Comment: @CensiLI Well, I know all the isomorphism theorems. i'm not asking that. I'm asking how you get the first isomorphism. When it is a field, for an algebraic number $\alpha$, one can do that by finding the minimal polynomial for it. However, I don't know how it works when it is not a field.

Comment: @Rubertos So your problem is why $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]\simeq\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-2)$ ? Define a ring homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}[X]\to\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ by $X\mapsto\sqrt{2}$. Then prove that $f$ is surjective and $\ker f=(X^2-2)$. There is no more difficulties than what you did in a field since  $X^2-2$ is a monic polynomial, and a monic polynomial behaves as nicely in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ as in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Comment: @CensiLI Ok now I understand that. But then $\mathbb[Z]^2/(3-\sqrt{2})\cong Z[X,Y]/(X^2-2,Y-3)$. How do you construct an isomorphism to $Z[X]$, not $Z[X,Y]$.

Comment: @Rubertos Why do you think $\mathbb[Z]^2/(3-\sqrt{2})\cong Z[X,Y]/(X^2-2,Y-3)$? I think $Z[X,Y]/(X^2-2,Y-3)\cong Z[\sqrt{2},Y]/(Y-3)\cong\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$

Comment: @CensiLI right my mistake. What i meant was that, you did not construct an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]/(3-\sqrt{2})\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-2,X-3)$, but just $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]/(\sqrt{2})\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-2)$. How do I generalize this to the original one?

Comment: @Rubertos I've noted above that it suffices to use the third isomorphism $(R/I)/(J/I)\cong R/J$ with $R$ being $\mathbb Z[X]$, $I$ being $(X^2-2)$ and $J$ being $(X^2-2,3-X)$.

Comment: @CensiLI aha! Thank you :)